# Utilizing multiple processors to load large number of files for pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to load hundreds or thousands of JSON files into a big pandas dataframe. My current solution using a for loop to iterate the directory is slow and is not utilizing the multiple CPUs of the machine.

I already a basic idea of putting all the filenames to load into a list and split it into a multiple chunks, and have each thread or process to work on each chunk.

What's the best way doing this in utilizing multiple CPUs? I thought of using fork but it seems that a child process cannot return a data structure to the parent process.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think that multiple cpus will help you with file-loading IO times? IO is slow. Period.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes, I agree with you that IO will still be the main bottleneck, But you still need to parse the JSON and for pandas do perform data transformation from JSON format to one used by  pandas dataframe.  Besides, modern IO such as SSD can do parallel reads.

Comment: Your idea sounds fine to me. Try [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#parallel). Limited functionality, but very easy to use. On a side note, I often use multiprocessing to read multiple files, and it is indeed several times faster than single-threaded.